# PHP MYSQL два SELECT основываясь на первом значении

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `chats`, в ней поля `id, lastupdate`. Так же есть таблица `members`, в ней поля `chatid, userid, lastvisit`.

Первый запрос является таковым:

```
SELECT  m.chatid, m.userid, c.lastupdate FROM chat1.members m, chat1.chats c 
WHERE  m.chatid IN 
(SELECT chatid FROM chat1.members WHERE userid = ?i) AND c.id = m.chatid 
AND m.userid <> ?i
```

При помощи него, делается выборка записей, где `chatid` равен тому же значению что и `chatid` нашего пользователя (см. IN SELECT). Далее в WHERE, мы указываем что выбирать данные нужно там, где userid не равен нашему, то есть получаем данные второго участника чата.

Далее я бы хотел сравнить значения поля `c.lastupdate` (последнее обновление чата) с последним **нашим** посещением чата (поле lastvisit, в таблице members m.)

Но дело в том, что в первом запросе вы выбрали данные другого участника нашего чата, и получается что нужно делать новый запрос, дабы выбрать теперь наши данные:

```
SELECT lastvisit FROM chat1.members WHERE chatid = ?i AND userid = ?i
```

И в конце концов у меня появляется вопрос, возможно ли эти запросы объеденить? Я пробовал делать так:

```
SELECT  m.chatid, m.userid, c.lastupdate FROM chat1.members m, chat1.chats c 
WHERE  m.chatid IN (SELECT chatid FROM chat1.members WHERE userid = ?i) AND c.id = m.chatid 
AND m.userid <> ?i 
UNION SELECT lastvisit FROM chat1.members WHERE chatid = m.chatid AND userid = ?i
```

Но дело в том что `UNION` запрос не может распознать `m.chatid`

Comment: UNION... Вы точно хотите получить ДВЕ записи? Да ещё с разным количеством полей (что невозможно даже тупо теоретически)? По-моему, достаточно просто добавить поле lastvisit в выходной список первого запроса...

Comment: @Akina я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в SQL запросах, просто суть в том что в первом запросе мы получаем участников чата в котором есть мы (находим chatid = chatid что  есть у нашего пользователя, только у других), и при этом сортируем так, чтобы данные о нашем пользователе не выбирались (userid не равно нашему), а во втором запросе мне как раз наоборот, нужно получить данные о нашем пользователе. И я не знаю как это объединить, вначале исключить данные о нашем пользователе, а потом их же выбрать.

Comment: Уберите в первом запросе условие AND m.userid <> ?i. А в список выборки добавьте поле lastvisit. Все. Запрос вернет вам 2 записи. уже на клиенте, прочитав обе записи, можете посмотреть какая из них касалась вашего пользователя, а какая другого и сравнить их поля