# MYSQL корректный запрос

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, можно ли, и как, получить **одним** запросом следующую информацию:

Из таблицы users, получить поля avatar, status, везде, кроме useridid <> $id, то есть информация о всех пользователях, кроме одного. Но при этом же, получить поле group только у пользователя где userid = исключенному раннее $id.

В результате мы получаем информацию о всех пользователях кроме одного, и получаем только один статус того самого "особенного пользователя".

Не спрашивайте зачем и почему, просто уже несколько часов ломаю голову, и хочу понять, возможно ли это сделать или нет.

Comment: А вот без вопроса "зачем" ну никак не выйдет. потому что не ясно что именно требуется получить. любой sql запрос возвращает _таблицу_. А таблица это такая двумерная, плоская, структура. у нее есть строки и колонки. И она строго прямоугольна. Т.е. у всех строк одинаковое количество колонок. если какая то колонка нужна хотя бы для одной строки, она должна быть у всех строк (хотя может быть NULL, например). так что скажите, где именно этот статус должен находится. лучше нарисуйте ту таблицу что должна получиться

Comment: И сегодня уже был подозрительно похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/772444/194569 только там автор то же не пояснил что должно получиться, а без этого ничего ответить не возможно :(